# Form validation is not working in Ajax form submitting

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I am building a small Blog App with comment Functionality so, I am trying to prevent `bad words` in comments. ( If anyone tries to add selected bad words then the error will raise ).

BUT when i add  `text validation` in `model field` and try to enter bad word then it is saving without showing any errors of `validation`.

When i try to save form without ajax then the error is validation successfully showing. BUT error is not showing in ajax.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20000, null=True, blank=True,validators=[validate_is_profane])
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def blog_detail(request, pk, slug):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(
        post=data)

        context = {'data':data,'comments':comments}

        return render(request, 'mains/blog_post_detail.html', context)

    if request.GET.get('action') == 'addComment':
        if request.GET.get('description') == '' or request.GET.get(
                'description') == None:
            return None
        else:
            comment = Comment(description=request.GET.get('description'),
                              post=data,
                              user=request.user)
            comment.save()

    return JsonResponse({'comment': model_to_dict(comment)})
```

blog_post_detail.html

```
{% for comment in comments %}

   {{comment.comment_date}}

                            <script>
                                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                                    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                                        $('#commentReadMore{{comment.id}}').click(function (event) {
                                            event.preventDefault()
                                            $('#commentDescription{{comment.id}}').html(
                                                `{{comment.description}}`)
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            </script>

{% endfor %}
```

I have tried many times but still not showing the validation error.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: There's no where in the code you've shown that's 'checking for bad words.'

Comment: I have added a `validator` in model field ( description ), if you notice. AND that validator contains `.txt` file of few words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model fields validators are not called automatically on calling `save`. You need to call one of the following methods to do that: `full_clean`, `clean_fields`, `validate_unique` as described in the section [Validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) of the documentation.

These methods are normally called by the *[model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)* if we are using one, greatly simplifying this process. I would highly recommend using one. If you want to change your current code though, you can do the follows, where you are saving the instance:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


comment = Comment(
    description=request.GET.get('description'),
    post=data,
    user=request.user
)
try:
    comment.full_clean()  # Perform validation
except ValidationError as ex:
    errors = ex.message_dict # dictionary with errors
    # Return these errors in your response as JSON or whatever suits you
comment.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much much , it is working correctly ( It is not adding comment with bad words ). BUT it is not showing any errors, Can you please tell me how can i show errors ?

Comment: @Coder With the previous revision of my answer for errors you would have just gotten 500 status code, I have added some code that shows how to get the error dictionary, you would have to return them in your response from that and then display using javascript.

Comment: Thanks again for your Help

Comment: BUT it saving again bad words

Comment: @Coder as I said you have to _return_ the errors in that `except` block, that comment is meant to be replaced by _some code_ you write, that will return an appropriate response.

Comment: Understood everything you said